# Show that $\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(1+b^3)(1+c^3)}}+\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{(1+c^3)(1+a^3)}} \geq \frac{4}{3}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, contest-math, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> For positive real numbers $a,b,c$ with $abc = 8$ prove that
>   $$
> \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}}
> + \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(1+b^3)(1+c^3)}}
> + \frac{c^2}{\sqrt{(1+c^3)(1+a^3)}}
> \geq \frac{4}{3}.
> $$

Can we prove this by Cauchy-Schwarz or Jensen's inequality? If not how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By AM-GM $\sqrt{a^3+1}\leq\frac{a+1+a^2-a+1}{2}=\frac{a^2+2}{2}$.

Hence, it remains to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)}\geq\frac{1}{3}$, which is

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b^2+2a^2)\geq72$, which is AM-GM again.

Comment: You might consider filling in the gap from the middle inequality to the last one.

Comment: Actually i can't understand how you got from the middle ineq to the last one... :P

Comment: It's $3\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2(c^2+2)\geq(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc }(a^2b^2+2a^2)\geq72$.

Comment: Sorry but i can't find out  how $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+2a^2) \geq 72$ is proved by AM-GM...

Comment: $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2b^2\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4c^4}=48$ and $2\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2\geq6\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=24$.